# How to change z-index on sprite properly?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have google it and I know that properly way to add z-index is by order of creating but I have different situation.

I'm creating card game and I want to move card on click and after that card should be on top which is not possible so I have solved in following way.

In function which is called on card click I'm destroying that card and creating identically new card which is on top because it is created last.

Is there another way of solving this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On card release you could use [BringToTop](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Component.BringToTop.html) (see also `moveDown`, `moveUp` and `sendToBack` methods that can be usefull to you)

Something like:

`game.world.bringToTop(activeCard);`

After this line, `activeCard` should be on top of all others sprites or groups.

Comment: that's the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

if the objects/sprites are not in the same group `game.world.bringToTop(target)` will not work. 
a more solid solution is to add objects to groups in the order you want them to be layered like so:

```
// Groups for drawing layers
var back_layer = game.add.group();
var mid_layer = game.add.group();
var front_layer = game.add.group();
// It doesn't matter what order you add things to these groups, the draw order will be back, mid, front (unless you change it...)
back_layer.create(0, 0, "bg");
front_layer.create(0, 0, "front");
mid_layer.create(300, 200, "object1");
mid_layer.create(500, 400, "object2");
```

explained here - [www.html5gamedevs.com post](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/14729-how-to-set-z-index-for-a-sprite/)

Personally I worked with both solutions and the groups one proved to be much more workable as the project starts to scale

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can test ordering with these;

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
game.global = {};
function preload () {
 
}
 
function create () {

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);  
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#01555f';
  
    this.gfx = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
    this.gfx.visible = false;
    this.gfx.beginFill(0x02C487, 1);  
    this.gfx.drawRect(100, 100, 250, 1);  
    this.barSprite = game.add.sprite(100, 500, this.gfx.generateTexture());    
    this.barSprite.anchor.y = 1;
    game.add.tween(this.barSprite).to({ height: 400 }, 1000, Phaser.Easing.Default, true, 0);
     
    var bubbleGfx = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
    bubbleGfx.lineStyle(2 * 1, 0x000000, 1);
    bubbleGfx.visible = true;
    bubbleGfx.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
    bubbleGfx.drawRoundedRect(300, 150, 200, 100, 8); 
     
    this.gfx2 = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
    this.gfx2.visible = false;
    this.gfx2.beginFill(0x02C111, 1);  
    this.gfx2.drawRect(150, 100, 250, 1);  
    this.barSprite2 = game.add.sprite(400, 500, this.gfx2.generateTexture());   
    this.barSprite2.anchor.y = 1; 
    game.add.tween(this.barSprite2).to({ height: 400 }, 1000, Phaser.Easing.Default, true, 0);
} 
function update () {
 
}
```

Comment: also, can use the group for objects.